# Cannot get the correct input in C programming

Tags: c

I am writing a simple C program to accept an input number from user and display it just because earlier i was writing some C program and this stupid error is bugging me it wasn't there before until yesterday

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Display number%d",&a);
}
```

Every time i run a program that accept an input it displays a seemingly random value and not the one I entered not just in this program in any other too, here 
is the O/p:
**Enter a number: 12 
  Display number : 2752300 
  Process returned 7(0X7) execution time : 1.880s
  Press any key to continue**

I don't know whether is the Compiler error or some memory error that is causing this problem but for the record i have tried using different IDE like DEV C/C++, Turbo C/C++ and Code Blocks but the error remains to be same in all of it except in Turbo C/C++ it display a signed number of i enter for eg : if input is 12 it displays: -12.

Comment: Don't post images of text! Was it really easier to make that snapshot instead of copy/paste those few lines?? And see what argument type `printf` takes! Compiler warnings are not for fun, but shall be taken seriously. Enable them and pay heed.

Comment: You are aware that it's possible to select text in a console window and copy it to the clipboard? Images should only be used when there is no other way to illustrate a problem. Unnecessary use of images is inappropriate for a whole lot of reasons. There's a list of reasons why you shouldn't post images of your code in [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576); the vast majority of those reasons also apply to unnecessary images related to text output to the console. Have some consideration.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry for that i will remember it for future

Comment: @MehulChachada: The [`edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37770362/edit) Link under the text exists intentinally. Guess what it is for ... - Please **edit** the text!

Comment: @Olaf i edited the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your print statement.  You are printing the address of a, not the value.  Use `print("%d",a);`

Comment: thanks it was a rookie mistake i spend all day fixing it :P

Comment: Most of us have been there

Answer (score 2):

The `%d` format specifier for `printf` expects an `int`, not an `int *`:

```
printf("%d",a);
```

It's not attempting to write to `a`, so it doesn't need its address.

If you compile with the warning level turned up (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc), it will tell you this:

```
format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf needs a pointer to the variable if it is going to    change the variable itself, so we use the address-of operator to get the pointer.

scanf()  received "%d", as a parameter and then knows it needs to read an integer and store it in the next variable in the argument list.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int main(void)
    {
     int a = 0;
     printf("Enter a number: ");
     scanf ("%d" ,&a);
     printf ("%d \n ",a);
return 0;
}
```